# program to calculate median conversion rate using the given visitors and conversions in the 99% credible interval. Beta(1,1) is prior

Tags: python, ab-testing

I'm looking for a solution where in I can find the 'median conversion rate' given the number of visitors and number of conversions in the 99% confidence level. (where Beta(1,1) is the prior)

I've taken some random values for visitors and conversions and calculated the conversion rate (in %) i.e conversions/visitors. Then I used the conversion rate and the visitors to calculate the standard error (SE) which was further multiplied by the alpha value (2.56 for 99% confidence level) in order to calculate the interval (adding and subtracting from the standard error)

I dont have a code just want to understand the methodology

Looking for some guidance